# To find out which properties of a given class are in use in different solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My requirement is : to find out which properties of a given class are in use  in different solutions and  how those are used(basically to retrieve the line of code so that we get to know the logic).

I am given  Seven Visual studio solutions and a class with some properties.
I need to go to every solution and  loop through every property of the given class and find out,

1. The line of code where this property is used.
2. The Method name in which the property is utilized.
3. The Class Name in which this method exists.
4. The project in which  this class exists.

And I need to store this information in a file. For Example in a Microsoft Excel document.
I need to do the above steps for all the variables  of the given input class.

Can you please help me how to achieve this? Can you please  suggest some tools or an algorithm to implement this.

The class which I am given has over 100 properties, and these properties can be enums(I saw one enum has 40 values) and other class instances also. So I need to find out in all the given seven different solutions, where all the properties in the given class are used..in the format, propertyName, code where this property is used(1 or 2 lines), method Name, className and the project Name. If possible Can you please suggest an algorithm(so that I can try to develop a tool) or any tools available? The basic requirement is to find out which fields are actually used in the given 7 solutions. I need to create a file with these details.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,

Siddi.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to create a new solution, and import all projects into that one. You could then use Visual Studio to search across all of them.